# Overriding css with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet

I have a table whose border is set as 1px solid silver from an external style sheet(some .css file). I have no control over this file.

This is the css:
my_table tbody td { 
font: 8.5pt verdana, sans-serif;
border-top: solid 1px silver;
border-bottom: solid 1px silver;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px 3px 0px 2px;
}

Now I want to change the border color of the last row in the table to black. Im trying to use the following jQuery statement for this.

```
$('#table_1 tr:last').css('border', '1px solid black');
```

But this does not seem to work. 
How can I do this with JQuery/JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the TDs you're after, you need to address them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#table_1 tr:last td').css('border', '1px solid black');
});
```

This code will wait for the DOM to be ready and then apply the border on the TDs in the last row.

**Edit:** Seeing your CSS declaration, you need to make the style more specific. Here's how (with the class name):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.my_table > tbody tr:last td').css('border', '1px solid black');
});
```

If worse comes to worse, go for `$('table.my_table > tbody tr:last td')`.

Comment: Something strange happens when I do this:
The bottom border only becomes black. Other borders are still silver.

But when I use 2px solid black, that gets applied to all borders.
Not really sure why this happens.

Comment: Sounds strange. Would you mind posting the code? Do you have anything else in the table?

Comment: Sorry Gert. Your answer is very useful. I did not mean to downvote. Im very new to this forum and I was playing around and that became a downvote. Im trying to undo that. Apologies once again!

Comment: This is my css:

.my_table tbody td {
    font: 8.5pt  verdana, sans-serif;
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
    border-top: solid 1px silver;
    border-bottom: solid 1px silver;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 2px;
}

My table is very simple. Just has 2 columns and 15 rows. No other javascript/jquery features.

'my_table' is the class for the table.

Basically last column has grandtotal and has to be prominent. So I want a black border for it. I now use the jquery code you provided

Comment: @user343409 Update your question with the CSS and use the code formatting feature.  It's much more readable that way.

Comment: Gert - I'm not absolutely sure, but I think there are issues with IE and styling `tr` and `td` elements. Doing a little testing, and that seems to be the case.

Comment: @user343409 - No problem. We all make mistakes.

Comment: Gert - Nevermind. It is not `<td>` elements. Just `<tr>`. I was having another issue.

Comment: Gert - If OP wants to simulate a border on a row, you could always just style the top and bottom with border, then the first and last `td` elements in the row with left and right borders, respectively.

Comment: $('table.my_table > tbody tr:last td') also gives the same problem

Comment: @patrick - Only problem with that approach is that there would be gaps if there's any cell spacing (there would be gaps).

Comment: Gert - Very true. I assumed OP has some control over the HTML and that spacing was not otherwise desired. Perhaps too many assumptions! ;o)

Comment: @user343409 - It seems that with one pixel, the bottom of the second last row overwrites the top of the black box. With two pixels black, it won't happen: http://jsfiddle.net/Dq6Rn/

Comment: @patrick - Here's an example with the full row: jsfiddle.net/RDYTH (code not optimized)

Comment: @Gert,Patrick - Thanks! I understand why borders don't appear correctly now

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid red !important";
```

or

```
$('#table_1 tr:last td').css('border', '1px solid black !important');
```